# Book suggestions about eigenfunction expansion method in PDE solutions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

I want to solve non-homogenous PDE's (or PDE's system) by the method. I am looking for the notes, books etc. including theory and examples with solution about the method.

If I find right book, I can buy the book. But I don' t find adequate materials on the internet. (May be I don' t know right keywords for the search.)

Comment: "by the help of the method" ??

Comment: @Hirak eigenfunction expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in my courses I used the:

[Applied Partial Differential Equations with Fourier Series and Boundary Value Problems: Pearson New International Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IZ0LMJK)

which covers basics like SoV, Greens functions, Fourier and yes, Eigenfunction expansions! It was a good introduction to the subject I'd say.

EDIT:

Also, google search for "eigenfunction expansion for pde" gave me lots of good hits.